# Mongoimport out of memory(?) at 2 GB of an import

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

So I'm trying to import 2.3 gb of JSON into Mongo using Mongoimport. After reaching 2 GB the import stalls, freezes, and kills my machine.

After looking around and finding lots of stuff about namespace issues, I tried to fix the problem by making sure I had the most recent 64bit build, but this fixed nothing.

Then I tried to import it while running Mongod with WiredTiger, which should, if I remember correctly, only function in a 64 bit environment anyway and enforce those conventions by default. Nope.

Whatever I do, the import always seems to fail at 2 GB and I get no error messages.

Is there a workaround or solution for importing datasets greater than 2 GB?

Comment: Are you absolutely positively sure you have the 64 bit version of MongoDB?

Comment: Yep. 

Eventually I "fixed" it by splitting the file manually and importing it that way.